# Trust my own CA on iOS

Tags: java, ios, iphone, spring, ssl

I'm trying to connect my iOS app to my java spring backend using ssl. As I am deploying my backend locally, I am trying to connect it using my own certificates for development.

For my spring backend, I have create my own CA, signed a certificate with it, and added them to a keystore.jks. I configured the app accordingly, and when I go to `https://localhost:8082/blabla`, AFTER trusting it, it works fine.

However, I have no way of trusting it on my iOS app, so it fails. I tried installing my Custom CA on my iphone, but still. The curious thing is on my iphone, on profiles, I can see my custom CA and it has the green tick and says verified. I thought this would have been enough to trust the other certificates

Any ideas on what I am missing/doing wrong?

Other info: 
On my iOS app I am using Alamofire to make the requests.

Comment: You installed the root, any intermediate and leaf certificates?

Comment: @Wain To my iphone I installed only the root. Inside the keystore.jks that I use to deploy my app I have the rootCA and a certificate signed by this root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a proper answer, but might be useful for someone:

I could not trust my own CA on an iphone, and could not connect unless putting the exception to ATS on `info.plist`.

However, [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) now exists and it's on open beta! You can get a proper certificate there and forget about it (As @zaph suggested, you have to remember to renew it after 90 days, also you need to have a proper domain). This was a better option at least for me than creating my own certs.

Comment: You can't "forget about", it needs to be renewed every 90 days.

Comment: @zaph Renewing is quite easy, so yeah, I actually do forget about it, for 90 days.

Comment: I just mentioned that because it is not obvious to everyone. Also forgetting to renew certificated even happens to big guys like Apple and Microsoft. ;-)